# How select all and add one column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I know that it is easy, but did not find it on the web. I want to select all columns and add one in the select command. I tried following but it did not help

```
SELECT *, (case when country= 'USA' then 'Brazil' when country = 'Brazil' then 'USA') as namev2 from db1
```

Can you help?

Comment: add some sample data and your expected output in tabular format

Comment: You already have it, just missing the "end" clause of the case/when.... case when condition then answer when next condition then answer end

Comment: Your `case` is missing an `end`. For future reference, always include your error message in your question. There's no need to make people guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your syntax have problem.

Try

```
SELECT 
db1.*, 
case 
    when 
        db1.country= 'USA' 
    then
        'Brazil' 
    when 
        db1.country = 'Brazil' 
    then 
        'USA'
END as namev2 from db1;
```